# NHibernate: Implementing ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I have 2 tables with manyToMany relationship.

```
public class User
{
   public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
   public virtual UInt64 UserId { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Group> Groups{ get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
   public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
   public virtual Guid GroupGuid  { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<User> Users{ get; set; }
}
```

I use Fluent NHibernate to AutoMap them as follows:

```
.Override<User>(obj => obj.HasManyToMany(x => x.Groups).Table("UserToGroup").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan())

.Override<Group>(obj => obj.HasManyToMany(x => x.Users).Table("UserToGroup").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse())
```

When I add a User which contains groups list, All table updated OK:
Insert of new user in User table. OK
Insert of new group in Group table. OK
Insert of new relation inUserToGroup table. OK

I use the following code to add a User (including groups):

```
public void AddUser(User userData, IList<Guid> groupIds)
{
   User user = new User();
   user.UserId = userData.UserId;

   IList<User> Users = new List<Users();
   Users.Add(user);

   IList<Group> groups = new List<Group>();

   foreach (Guid groupId in groupIds)
   {
      Group grp = new Group();
      grp.GroupGuid = groupId;
      grp.Users = Users;
      groups.Add(grp);
   }

   user.Groups = groups;
   Session.Save(user);
}
```

The problem:
When I add a new User that contains a GroupGuid that is already exist in Group table, a new record is inserted to Group table with the same GroupGuid and new id.

Questions:

1. How do I make NHibernate adding only new GroupGuid ids to Group table ? and still add a relation in UserToGroup table which related the new User to the exist Group.
2. In AddUser method - should I set both side with entity i.e. set user.Groups with group list and set group.Users with user list ?

Thanks,
Haimon.

Comment: Can you show the code where you populate the groups for the user?

Comment: @MartinErnst you can see the groups population in code after "I use the following code to add a User (including groups):"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are experiencing this is because you are likely using unassociated Group entities when you associate them with your User object. So you need to load them from the database.

Alternatively, you can switch to using the Guids as the id for the entity, instead of whatever other primary key you've set up.

To answer your second question, you should just be able to set one side of the relationship. However, I'm confused as to why you would have 2 separate tables for the relationship. You typically only need 1 other table:

```
User
Group
UserGroup
```

Comment: 1. by saying that I nee to load the, from DB you mean that I should you Session.Load to all groupIds which I want to add to user? how can do it if groupId property is not my table id ? Regarding switching to use GroupGuid as my id, I can't use it since the value of it isn't set by Hibernate but I get it by the application (I cannot use Hibernate generation of this property). Regarding you last section: I am using only one table for the relationship between 2 entities. UserGroup is the relationship table between User and Grroup

Comment: 1. I didn't understand how can I load the group entities from the database? (Using Session.Load/QueryOver?) 2. Regarding using Guids - Currently I use Guid Id (which is the Id and PK and is generated by hibernate) and I also have a Guid property named: GroupGuid which I get by the application (not PK not Id and isn't generated by Hibernate but supplied by application). what do you mean by switching to Guid - I already use Guid (GroupGuid). If you meant that I shell work only with GroupGuid and it should be the table ID and PK - how can I do it without having Hibernate generating it for me?

Comment: @Haimon 1. Yes, you would use them either with Session.Load or with some kind of query.
2. You can use assigned as a generator type http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-assigned and rely on your application to assign the ids.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It work by setting Id of Group entity to GroupGuid value in constructor. And by setting Id to be generated.assign (now I have 2 columns with the same value). I couldn't set GroupGuid to be the entity Id since it is a property in a component in Group Entity. Do you know if it possible in AutoMap setting Id of a property which is in a component of an entity ?